# How to implement video call with twilio task router

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-taskrouter

We are using Task Router for our Call Center Project.  Incoming calls routing through Task Router to our agents.  Now, We have to impliment Video Call as well.  I want to understand, how we can use Same Task Router for Voice Call and Video call to distribute to our Agents ?

Is there any code of reference example to use that ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We have one example of a multichannel contact centre that is powered by TaskRouter. You can see it on GitHub here: https://github.com/nash-md/twilio-contact-center.

When you integrate Voice with TaskRouter, the TwiML integration makes it straightforward to create tasks by enqueueing the call to a workflow. When you are working with other inputs you need to manually create the tasks and handle the assignment on the other end too. This app should help you see how that works.

I'm not super familiar with the codebase myself, but you probably want to start by checking out the [task controller](https://github.com/nash-md/twilio-contact-center/blob/master/controllers/tasks.js) which starts video chat rooms and creates a task to match. Then the [workflow controller](https://github.com/nash-md/twilio-contact-center/blob/9d851c9dd365f2048066355783b4403e6ae12d68/public/callcenter/WorkflowController.js#L204) is the client side component that deal with receiving, accepting or denying reservations.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: but this all are js can you give me in php

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a PHP example available, this is the best one we have at the moment I'm afraid.

Comment: but i don't know about angular js

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the time to translate the entire app myself and this is all we've got as an example of Video and Voice and TaskRouter all in the same app.

Comment: I'm not in the position to write a video and taskrouter app in PHP right now. I recommend you check out the documentation on the [TaskRouter REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/tasks) and [creating tasks and accepting reservations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/taskrouter/reservations-create-task-rest). Then tie that back together with a Video app. If you have specific questions, then please do ask them on SO with the Twilio tag and I will try to help then.

Comment: ok thanks giving information.
but i done video call with task router.

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear that you have managed to integrate Video with TaskRouter. Hope the rest of your app goes well :)